# Spring boot and Tomcat : Is it better to use embeded Tomcat or external Tomcat installation.

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, embedded-tomcat-7

I was wondering if some experienced spring boot users can tell us how to choose between embedded Tomcat and external Tomcat installation.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It really depends on you/your organization decision and decision is based on various things including infrastructure you have or planning to have. So there is no way one can say go with this without looking in details.

Comment: Thank you @want2learn !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded Tomcat helps you to define Standalone application. Earlier we have to deploy war to Tomcat Server which itself a tedious task. From the embedded tomcat you can run application as service without worrying about the deployment thing. As now days microservices are being popular, spring boot is more popular because of its feature one of them is embedded servers like Tomcat,Jetty or Netty.